# Pull-backs which are push-outs

Tags: ct.category-theory

Consider a commutative square in a category $\mathcal{C}$
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A&\rightarrow&B\\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\\
C&\rightarrow&D
\end{array}$$
Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is abelian. If this square is a pull-back and $B\rightarrow D$ or $C\rightarrow D$ is an epimorphism, then this square is also a push-out square. Dually, if this square is a push-out and $A\rightarrow B$ or $A\rightarrow C$ is a monomorphism, then this square is also a pull-back square. ¿Are there more general kinds of categories were such things happen?

Comment: Try to look for *effective epimorphisms*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes! [Pretoposes](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopos) (and in particular toposes) also have this property. It is a remarkable fact that pretoposes (which you can think of as having the first-order exactness properties of toposes or $Set$-like categories) have "most" of the same exactness properties as abelian categories (see below).

In fact, this is the beginning of a remarkable set of observations due to Peter Freyd, and expounded by him in a [discussion](http://www.mta.ca/~cat-dist/catlist/1999/atcat) at the categories mailing list, which led to a sharp distinction between pretoposes and abelian categories as concentrated particularly in the behavior of the initial object. (In an abelian category, $A \times 0 \cong A$, whereas in a pretopos $A \times 0 \cong 0$. But this is practically the only essential difference.) In fact, Freyd showed that abelian categories and pretoposes are special cases of what he dubbed "AT categories", which contain the core exactness properties which are common to abelian categories and pretoposes. AT categories cut so close to the essence of each of these two special cases that in fact every AT category splits cleanly as a product of an abelian category and a pretopos!

I wrote up my own account of this in the nLab, [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AT+category).

Comment: The question could almost have been written as a deliberate feedline to give this wonderful answer a home on MO!

Comment: Heh, thanks Peter! I was delighted to have this question fall into my lap, as it were. The idea of AT category is very cool, but I'm not aware that much has been done with it since those discussions between Freyd and Pratt. 

Comment: One might argue that the idea of AT category is so neat that it destroys itself as an object to be studied: since any AT category splits into an abelian category and a pretopos, why study AT categories rather than just abelian categories and pretopoi separately?


Comment: I've often wondered about that too, Mike. I don't have an answer to that. 

Comment: Hi Todd, thanks for your answer. I've had a look at your links and I've found that pretoposes have the second property I mentioned. Do they also have the first one?

Comment: Fernando, pretoposes do not have the first property. In fact even the category Set does not have this property: consider the case where $C=0$.

Comment: Actually Freyd intended his argument to show that AT categories are not interesting, and are a special case of a much more general uninteresting situation.

Comment: @Colin: Interesting. Where does he say that? 

Comment: @Todd: His point on the cat list is that there nothing new in the common theory of pretoposes and ab cats.  As to elementary properties, the common ground of any two first order theories is just their disjunction.  As to Horn properties or AE properties every product of pretoposes and abelian categories is a model.  Conversely the interesting logical fact is that nothing else happens in this theory.  Merely multiplying by 0 separates any model into one ab cat and one pretopos.  this is the same trick as multiplying by idempotents in commutative algebra or in topos theory.  

Comment: @Colin: Yes, I see that point. 

Comment: Is there a property like this in Higher Topos Theory, using homotopy monomorphisms?

Comment: @OrenBen-Bassat Sadly, my feeling for higher topos theory is not all that it could or should be. However, ...

Comment: I'm copying @MikeShulman to alert him to your question (Oren), as he would have a much better chance of saying something meaningful.

Comment: @OrenBen-Bassat If you mean the property that a pushout of a mono is also a pullback, I think this follows from the generalized Blakers-Massey theorem https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09050. In particular, the "little Blakers-Massey theorem" (Corollary 4.1.4) says that the pushout of $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to C$ is a pullback if $\Delta f \Box_A \Delta g$ is invertible.  Since the diagonal $\Delta f$ of a mono is invertible (essentially by definition of "mono"), and any pushout product $\Box$ of an invertible map is invertible, the result follows.

Comment: perfect, thanks!